# Не запускается pgAdmin4. The pgAdmin 4 server could not be contacted:

Tags: база-данных, postgresql

При попытке запустить pgAdmin4 выдается данная ошибка(смотрите снизу). Введя в командной строке netstat -ano, убедился, что ни один процесс не взаимодействует с портом 5432.
Зайдя в службы Windows, не увидел службу PostgreSQL. Попытки запустить данную службу и переустановка не помогли. Пытался скинуть логи - не помогло. Что еще можно предпринять в данной ситуации?
Справка:
ОС - Windows 7.
Версия PostgreSQL - 14.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]